# How can I get the content of the version string property of my latest app version available in the App Store using Swift/ iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, app-store

Dear stack overflow community,

I wish to get the content of the version string property of the latest version of my iOS app available in the app store, based on the App ID, using Swift.

Basically I want to change the following Objective-C code to relate on the App ID instead of the bundle ID and I wish to translate it to Swift:

```
NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString* bundleID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", bundleID]];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
    NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
}
```

While I should be able to translate the code to swift pretty easily I don't know yet how to make it depend on the App ID instead of the bundle ID. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is this question being down voted? Please help to improve the way questions are being asked by commenting. Thanks

Comment: Users don't have to comment when voting, this has been discussed at length on meta.stackoverflow. The best way to learn how to ask good questions is to read [How to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help section.

Comment: Sorry Eric but your comment has been not helpful at all as every single point listed on the page you linked already has been considered:

“Write a title that summarizes the specific problem“ - check
“Introduce the problem before you post any code“ - check
“Help others reproduce the problem“ - check
“Include all relevant tags“ - check
“Proof-read before posting!“ - check
“Post the question and respond to feedback“ - check
“Look for help asking for help“ - check

Comment: It was helpful because you've read the linked page, and it was the purpose of the comment. :) Now keep in mind that you got ONE downvote (and it's been countervoted since). I wouldn't seriously make any conclusions based on such a tiny localized act. IF your questions are *often* downvoted then ask yourself why; otherwise everything is ok. Related (and funny): http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/288658

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which field you mean when you say "App ID" but the way you can find the answer is to open your info.plist file in Xcode, right click in the file content area, and choose Show Raw Keys/Values.

You'll see the key CFBundleIdentifier that represents the bundle id.  Find the corresponding key that matches the "App ID" that you want to use and substitute it in the code you're going to convert.  (CFBundleExecutable maybe?)

Comment: I read somewhere on stack overflow that the bundle identifier might change over time and thus be not suitable to identify your app. Someone suggested to use the "App ID". However, this seems to be nonsense since the App ID includes the bundle ID according to apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/AppID.html    So I guess I can just go with the bundle ID?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you have total control over the bundle id.  If you change it, iOS will treat the result as a new app even if everything else about the product is the same.  (Ah, I see...  App ID = Team id + bundle id.  ...haven't had a reason to use that.)